# How to skip all onchange evetns exept first one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where user can edit any cell and i have onchange event for all this cells. But I also have some special cells that should be processed in some other way:

```
$('#table_id td[col="from"]').on('change', function(evt, newValue){
    console.log('Special cell');
});
$('#operators td').on('change', function(evt, newValue){
    console.log('Any cell')
});
```

But in this case I can see both records in console if I'm editing Special cell:

```
Special cell
Any cell
```

And I want to see only 'Special cell'

UPD: They say I should use `stopImmediatePropagation()`. What do you think?

Comment: can you please provide your html ?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle example or create snippet for your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[attribute not equal selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)** in case of normal cells:

```
$('#operators td[col!="from"]').on('change', function(evt, newValue){
   console.log('Any cell')
});
```